# MvvmCross binding with NSTableView

Tags: macos, xamarin, mvvmcross, nstableview

After searching multiple blogs and videos I find that to implement the `UITableView` one can use `MvxTableViewController`, but what to use for `NSTableView`?

I do not find any tutorial, example that covers OSX binding TableView using MvvmCross. Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

We don't have `MvxTableViewController` for macOS.

However, if you abstract from that, binding to a `NSTableView` is very similar to a `UITableView` on iOS.

```cs
private NSTableView _tableView;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    _tableView = new NSTableView();

    // add constraints or size otherwise

    var source = new MvxTableViewSource(_tableView);
    _tableView.Source = source;

    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyViewController, MyViewModel>();
    set.Bind(source).For(v => v.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Items);
    set.Apply();
}
```

This will bind the ViewModel `Items` to the `ItemsSource`. However, you will still need to specify what to bind in the cell. The simplest way to do this is to provide a TableColumn.

```cs
var column = new MvxTableColumn();
column.Identifier = "First";
column.BindingText = "Text Name";
column.HeaderCell = new NSCell("Example");
_tableView.AddColumn(column);
```

This will bind the `Text` property of the TableColumn to `Name` in the items provided in `Items` in the ViewModel.

If you need more than this you will need to subclass `MvxTableViewSource` and override `GetOrCreateViewFor` and in there provide your own subclass of `MvxTableCellView` where you do more. This could look something as follows.

```cs
public class MyCustomCell : MvxTableCellView
{
    public MyCustomCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public MyCustomCell(string bindingText) : base(bindingText)
    {
        this.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
        TextField = new NSTextField(new CGRect(50, 0, 100, 50))
        {
            Editable = false,
            Bordered = false
        };

        ImageView = new NSImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 50, 50));

        AddSubview(TextField);
        AddSubview(ImageView);
        this.Initialize(bindingText);
    }

    private string _imageUrl;
    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get => _imageUrl;
        set
        {
            _imageUrl = value;
            ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(_imageUrl).Into(ImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

And the table source:

```cs
public class MyTableSource : MvxTableViewSource
{
    private string _bindingText;

    public MyTableSource(NSTableView tableView, string bindingText) : base(tableView)
    {
        _bindingText = bindingText;
    }

    public override NSView GetViewForItem(NSTableView tableView, NSTableColumn tableColumn, nint row)
    {
        if (ItemsSource == null)
            return null;

        var item = ItemsSource.ElementAt((int)row);
        var view = new MyCustomCell(_bindingText);

        if (view is IMvxDataConsumer bindable)
            bindable.DataContext = item;

        return view;
    }
}
```

Then instead of using `MvxTableViewSource` in the first example, use your own `MyTableSource` instead:

```cs
var source = new MyTableViewSource(_tableView, "Text Name; ImageUrl Url");
_tableView.Source = source;
```

Where `Name` and `Url` are in the Item in the `Items` bound to the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did some changes and I am getting rows (not with correct data, that I will figure out). I have `tableView` as an outlet and modified some parts as:    `//bind table view
   var source = new MvxTableViewSource(tableView);
            tableView.Source = source;
   set.Bind(source).For(v => v.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Items);`

Comment: But how to bind the contents of the table view?

Comment: I will elaborate :)